# Aplicar AsyncTask no código que recebe paramentos double

Tags: java, android

Estou com muitas duvidas de como aplicar o conceito de `AsyncTask`.
Gostaria de saber como ficaria este codigo em `AsyncTask`. Obrigado desde já

```
// Metodo da ação do botão Calcular 

public void Calculaar(View view) {

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {

            try {

                        String v1 = av1.getText().toString();
                        String v2 = av2.getText().toString();
                        String v3 = av3.getText().toString();
                        String v4 = av4.getText().toString();

                        if (v1.trim().isEmpty() || v2.trim().isEmpty() || v3.trim().isEmpty() || v4.trim().isEmpty()) {
                            AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(Tela_Pres.this);
                            dlg.setMessage("Há Dados em Branco!");
                            dlg.setNeutralButton("Ok", null);
                            dlg.show();

                        } else {


                            AV1 = Double.parseDouble(av1.getText().toString());
                            AV2 = Double.parseDouble(av2.getText().toString());
                            AV3 = Double.parseDouble(av3.getText().toString());
                            AV4 = Double.parseDouble(av4.getText().toString());


                            resultado = ((AV1 * 2) + (AV2 * 2) + (AV3 * 1) + (AV4 * 1)) / 6;

                            DecimalFormat formato = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
                            resultado = Double.valueOf(formato.format(resultado));


                            if (resultado < 6) {


                                resultadoText.setText(String.valueOf("Sua Média: " + resultado + " , Aluno Reprovado"));
                                AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(Tela_Pres.this);
                                dlg.setMessage("Resultado: " + resultado + " Aluno Reprovado");
                                dlg.setNeutralButton("Ok", null);
                                dlg.show();


                            } else {
                                resultadoText.setText(String.valueOf("Sua Média:  " + resultado + " , Aluno Aprovado"));

                                AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(Tela_Pres.this);
                                dlg.setMessage("Resultado:   " + resultado + ", Parabéns Aluno Aprovado");
                                dlg.setNeutralButton("Ok", null);
                                dlg.show();
                            }
                        }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Não é recomendado alterar a interface a partir de uma thread, você deve colocar tudo o que altera a interface do usuário na thread principal. No seu caso dá pra validar a entrada do usuário antes de chamar a AsyncTask, e mostrar o resultado no método `onPostExecute`:

```
new AsyncTask<Double, Void, Double> () {
    public Double doInBackground(Double... params) {
        AV1 = params[0];
        AV2 = params[1];
        AV3 = params[2];
        AV4 = params[3];

        return ((AV1 * 2) + (AV2 * 2) + (AV3 * 1) + (AV4 * 1)) / 6;
    }

    public void onPostExecute(Double resultado) {
        if (resultado < 6) {
            resultadoText.setText("Sua Média: " + resultado + " , Aluno Reprovado");
            AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(Tela_Pres.this);
            dlg.setMessage("Resultado: " + resultado + " Aluno Reprovado");
            dlg.setNeutralButton("Ok", null);
            dlg.show();

        } else {
            resultadoText.setText("Sua Média:  " + resultado + " , Aluno Aprovado");
            AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(Tela_Pres.this);
            dlg.setMessage("Resultado:   " + resultado + ", Parabéns Aluno Aprovado");
            dlg.setNeutralButton("Ok", null);
            dlg.show();
        }
    }   

}.execute(Double.parseDouble(av1.getText().toString()), 
        Double.parseDouble(av2.getText().toString()),
        Double.parseDouble(av3.getText().toString()),
        Double.parseDouble(av4.getText().toString()));
```

Mas, a não ser que isso seja só um exemplo, não vale a pena usar uma thread pra fazer esse cálculo, pois ele é tão simples que o java vai demorar mais pra criar a thread do que pra executá-lo.

Comment: Sua resposta ficaria melhor se você explicasse por que não é recomendado alterar a interface gráfica a partir de outra thread.